# How do I get information about the server my app is running on in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How can i get more info about the server's status my spring boot app is running on? I want to pass this information to an admin dashboard.

On nodejs we use [os module](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html) like so

```
var os = require('os');
console.log("Platform: " + os.platform());
console.log("Architecture: " + os.arch());
```

How do I get the uptime, total memory and free memory in spring boot(or java) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `System.getProperty()` method for this. Here is an example.

```java
String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
String osArch = System.getProperty("os.arch");
```

For a comprehensive list of system properties available in java, read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).

Comment: Is architecture, name and version the only viewable properties?

Comment: According to the doc (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html), yes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want you could try using Spring Boot Actuator, it is a module developed specifically to retrieve various metrics from the server on which it is implemented, there is the dependency.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

You can reach the metrics through the REST Api at /actuator/metrics.
For a complete documentation you can take a look [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/actuator-api/htmlsingle/)

Comment: Is it okay to use actuator in production?

Comment: Absolutely, it is made for production